# mongoose delete from array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I need to remove the user's id from all objects in the collection except the one that was passed, in my example it is value: 'Тата', tell me how to make such a request?

[image]

console.log(result)

```
[
 {
    _id: 5fa702b2f18e5723b4c00d9f,
    value: 'Тата',
    vote: { '36e7da32-f818-4771-bb5e-1807b2954b5f': [Array] },
    date: 2020-11-07T20:25:22.611Z,
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

console.log(req.body)

```
{ value: 'Тата', habalkaId: '36e7da32-f818-4771-bb5e-1807b2954b5f' }
```

console.log(req.user._id)

```
5f63a251f17f1f38bc92bdab
```

that's all I could do, just find

```
router.post('/', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), (req, res) => {
   FirstName.find({value: req.body.value})
    .then(result => {
      if (result.length) {
        console.log(result)
        console.log(req.body)
        console.log(req.user._id)
        FirstName.find({value: {$ne: 'Слоник'}}, function (err, arr) {
            arr.map(e => {
              if (e.vote[req.body.habalkaId].length) {
                if(e.vote[req.body.habalkaId].includes(String(req.user._id))){
                  console.log(e.vote[req.body.habalkaId])
                }
              }
            })

        })

      } else {
        new FirstName({
          value: req.body.value,
          vote: {[req.body.habalkaId]: [String(req.user._id)]}
        }).save();
      }
    })

  // res.json({res: req.body})
})
```

FirstName.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const FirstNameSchema = new Schema({
  value: {
    type: String
  },
  vote: {
    type: Object
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = FirstName = mongoose.model('firstname', FirstNameSchema);
```

Comment: Can you post your collection example, please?

Comment: added, look in end question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understand well, you want something like this:

```js
db.collection.update({
  "value": {
    "$ne": "tata"
  }
},
{
  "$pull": {
    "vote.array_name": "id_value"
  }
},
{
  multi: true
})
```

First of all, find all document that not match the `value` with the given one. Then, for each document found, delete the object from the array, using `$pull` where the `id` given matches.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/w1KbqBwqmvy)

Please check the payground and check if I've used the correct schema and it shows the expected output.

Comment: "array_name": [
        {
          0: "id_value"
        }
      ]
it is not an array of objects, but just an array just the compass shows so
[ '5f63a251f17f1f38bc92bdab' ] this is how it actually looks

Comment: i try this FirstName.update({
            "value": {
              "$ne": "Тата"
            }
          },
          {
            "$pull": {
              "vote.36e7da32-f818-4771-bb5e-1807b2954b5f": req.user._id
            }
          },
          {
            multi: true
          })
but don't work

Comment: ok i found my mistake, FirstName.update({
            "value": {
              "$ne": "Тата"
            }
          },
          {
            "$pull": {
              "vote.36e7da32-f818-4771-bb5e-1807b2954b5f": String(req.user._id)
            }
          },
          {
            multi: true
          })

paste it please instead of your code

Comment: That's true, sorry! That's the `compass` output. I've updated the answer.